# Gulp module shell/preprocess not executing command (setting env variable)

Tags: node.js, gulp

```
shell.task([
    'export NODE_ENV="development"'
]);
```

This won't work either:

```
preprocess({
    context: {
        NODE_ENV: 'development'
    }
});
```

This won't set my env variable. Any ideas? I'm using NVM with a node instance of v0.11.

Comment: If you set the variable in `gulp-preprocess`, it does not set the shell environment, but the variable for the processed files. If you set the variable in `gulp-shell`, it should be just set during the execution of this very task. Do you want to set it permanently? I'm not sure you can do that out of gulp. Let's ask some different question: Why do you want to change your env variable?